# emacs: file on command line is different than opening file later

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs24 in Ubuntu 15.10.

Emacs behaves differently when I specify a file on the command line when starting it versus opening the file later.  Specifically, if I say

```
emacs -Q a.org
```

then the org mode pulldown menu is correct.  But if I do

```
emacs -Q
```

followed by

```
C-x C-f a.org
```

then the org mode pulldown menu is wrong.  However SFAIK this is not an issue specifically with org-mode.

The -Q is to disable loading all initialization and site files.

So, my specific question is, how does emacs find a file differently when it's on the command line?

Also, how could I have researched this w/o bothering stackoverflow (I did the usual searches).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give more details about "the org pulldown menu is wrong"? What exactly is different from what you expect?

Comment: If I do not start emacs with an org file on the command line, then the org pulldown menu has entries for the lisp-interaction menu, and the tbl menu and text menus are blank.  This was reported as an org-mode bug several years ago.   However, whoever's bug this is, it is being triggered by a difference in how emacs is processing a file on the command line.  I also have a 2nd example not involving org-mode.   However it involves a long init file, and would be messy to reduce to a simple example.